# Bounty description missing in iOS app

Tags: feature-request, bug, bounties, ios-app

When I click the bounty info icon on the iOS app. The added bounty description and reason is not shown.png

**For example:**

[image: bounty description missing]

Comment: Same in android app, probably the API doesn't return that information.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Then I suggest adding that info to the API and all apps ;).

Comment: The API does return this information, but just as a generic post notice which doesn't appear to be related to the bounty.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize your goal was to remove your past name. If important enough, you can also flag the question and ask to redact the previous revisions, leaving only the latest revision,

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will do that. Not so important but wouldn't hurt either.