# No info about user who protect or lock the question in the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, bug, ios-app, protected-questions, locked-questions

Closed question has a banner with "i" button on the right. Tapping on it opens a block with additional information, in particular - user who close the question:

> [image: closed]

But protected or locked posts don't contain such "i" button:

> [image: protected]

> [image: locked]

Information about locker or protector can be obtained via revisions though.

I'm not sure is this a bug or feature request. So added both tags :)

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Wi-Fi)
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: Pretty sure it's because the API doesn't return the info, same as bounty info

Comment: @Cai questions with an open bounty have banner with "i". [Try here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286729/339911).

Comment: I meant the lack of bounty description (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281817/307988)).

Comment: Checked and API [`question`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) only returns `locked_date` and `protected_date`, no user info.